# Editar valor de data dentro de um dataframe

Tags: python, loop, pandas, dataframe, replace

[image: Print do DataFrame]

Eu tenho este DataFrame e a data está no seguinte formato: '2020-08-01'

Eu gostaria de escrever um loop que iterasse em cada linha e realizasse a troca para o seguinte formato: '01/08'

Estou usando o Jupyter, pandas... Muito Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O pandas tem a função strftime se consegue converter a data para uma string com o formato que você quer. [Link para documentação.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

`df["Date"].dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y")`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função apply do Pandas.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html

Exemplo:

```
def convert_data(dt):
    # Formata a data aqui
    return new_dt

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(convert_data)
```